# move Exchange 2010 message tracking logs

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm decommissioning a couple of Exchange 2010 CAS/HT servers that have a couple of weeks of message tracking logs on them. I'd like to move the logs somewhere where they can still be searched using the `Get-MessageTrackingLogs` cmdlet.

My first thought was to just move them to another CAS/HT server but apparently they are named exactly the same on all of the servers.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*"Search Message Tracking Logs"*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926.aspx) section from the documentation states:

> *You can't copy the message tracking log files from another Exchange server and then search them by using the Get-MessageTrackingLog cmdlet. Also, if you manually save an existing message tracking log file, the change in the file's date-time stamp breaks the query logic that Exchange uses to search the message tracking logs.*

But as the logs are plain text files in a simplistic structure you would be able to rename the log files to integrate them with the existing ones on a different server. The file name is something along `MSTRKyyymmdd-n.log` where `n` is an increment with a maximum of 9999. If you have not used a copy method which would pertain the last write access time stamp, you probably would want to set the copied files' last write timestamps [e.g. using the `LastWriteTime` property of the `FileInfo` object](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx) accordingly.

Events obviously would not be in a chronological order - this might impact searchability by time (not sure if it really is going to be the case). I simply would try it out with a couple of manually renamed log files and script a renaming function for the rest, if it works out.

You also could pull the data using `Get-MessageTrackingLog` and dump it to a file using `Export-Clixml` so you could reload it later and filter on the results using Powershell functions, if needed. This however would require you to use a different function to load the object and deprive you of `Get-MessageTrackingLog`-specific filters.

Comment: You were almost right about copying the log files, but there is one more step: you have to change the log files filesystem timestamps because Exchange uses them to choose which ones to search. There's a script here to do that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926.aspx

Comment: @longneck thanks for pointing this out. I'll add it to my answer for increased readability

Comment: You're right, that was the wrong link. But you found the right one. :)